# disable prompt "confirm open URL" in bot emulator?

Tags: json, visual-studio, bots, botframework, chatbot

I have a adaptive card in my bot framework project where I get user input , and in one specific button (adaptivecard.json) I'm performing it to open the web link.
 `{ "type": "Action.OpenUrl", "title": "Help", "url": "${help}", // "style": "positive", // "fallback": false, "id": "2" },`

when clicking that particular button it asking a prompt window "confirm open url?" , How do i disable this warning and open the link directly without any alert?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with the production version of Emulator. This was a behavior configured through electron with the Emulator build.

You can clone, change and build the [Emulator repository](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator). Unfortunately I'm not sure what the exact change would be, but if you are wanting to go this route, I could try and find out.